# How do I uninstall Android Eclipse after installing Android Studio on Windows

Tags: eclipse

I've been developing using Android Eclipse and recently migrated my projects to Android Studio. How can I remove Eclipse from my Windows 7 PC (without breaking Android Studio)? Interestingly, Android Eclipse isn't displayed in Windows' "Uninstall or change a program" window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is not installed.. Usually, it is just a .zip package that you decompress and use.

That's why you cant view it in "Uninstall or Change Program"

So, just find Eclipse folder location and delete whole folder!